# Google Sheets list key with highest value in key value pair

Tags: worksheet-function, google-sheets

I have a some data in key-value pairs setup like so:

---

```
     A           B
1  Key:        Value:
2  Cars          5
3  Bikes         4
4  Vans          9
5  Trucks        6
```

What I can't seem to figure out (mind-block) is the formula to answer this:

```
Product with higest sales:    <answer should be 'Vans'>
```

What formula would I need to get the result `Vans`? I've tried this:

```
 =FILTER(A2:A6, MAX(B2:B6))
```

To which I get an error stating that the Fliter has mismatched array sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a *condition*, not just a value, for the `FILTER` function.

So:

```
=FILTER(A2:A6, B2:B6 = MAX(B2:B6))
```

I have set up [a demonstration spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gPt7eVeSlcFx2P1Yvo8khOQD7jhbp2QSUWvIxGT4Ldg/edit?usp=sharing) for this, feel free to have a look or copy it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for migrating the question (I'm going to safely assume you did it) and for answering. That worked as expected. +1

Comment: Nah, I didn't migrate it, I'm not often at [su]. But Google Spreadsheets questions have a pretty good chance of getting a response here at [webapps.se].